# What is the yum command to install Eclipse Indigo for Java EE developers?

Tags: eclipse, centos, yum

I want to install Eclipse Indigo for Java EE developers in CentOS through `yum` command.

```
yum install eclipse ...
```

What is the exact command?

Comment: I recommend installing all java-programs, eclipse, tomcat, maven and so on, as well as jdk, directly from their respective homepages, into /usr/local, /opt or any other place you prefer, and set your $PATH and $XY_HOME accordingly, and so that your versions override any outdated versions yum has added to path already. Any frameworks or libraries should be installed through Maven (or any other dependency management system you use). (For eclipse and maven you can alternatively put links into /usr/local/bin like Ross suggest below, for the jdk-binaries I suggest you just update $PATH)

Comment: I think it's no longer possible to install eclipse via yum.

Answer (score 4):

Download the Eclipse archive from the Eclipse website. Unpack it in a suitable location. The unpacked directory tree includes the executable. It is not packaged using RPM. The RedHat (and other O/S) provided versions are usually very old and do not include the Java EE Eclipse modules.

Comment: Still relevant today. You are most likely to get a tar.gz file, extract this into /opt/ and link the eclipse/eclipse binary to /usr/bin/eclipse as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
yum install eclipse-platform
```

for the latest eclipse version :)
If you want JEE you can install the plugin afterwards

Edit:
For CentOS 8 you have to enable the eclipse module and install the package:

```
 dnf module enable eclipse
 dnf install eclipse
```

Comment: No package eclipse-platform available.

Comment: @Line please take a look at the date. In 2014 this package was available. In the meantime it was renamed https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Eclipse

Comment: to eclipse? maybe the answer is worth editing then. anyway, I cannot install _eclipse_ package as well as _eclipse-platform_ ;_;

Comment: moreover, you have a link to Fedora site while this question is about CentOS

Comment: @Line you should think about what Fedora is and what CentOS is, maybe this will help you to understand why I posted the Fedora link.

Comment: actually I did! I did search on it and it seems like they are separate operating systems. I also looked for a similar website for centOS and found information that there isn't any. https://serverfault.com/questions/239205/official-online-rpm-package-browser-search-for-centos. please correct me where I am wrong. also am I right that on centOS 7 you cannot acutally install eclipse using yum like in the question?

Comment: CentOS is based on fedora, it's the same code base. Even if both are different OS, most OS components are the same. CentOS is the long term support server OS, while Fedora is the short term support workstation OS.

It depends on your CentOS version how you could install eclipse. In CentOS 8 you simply use "dnf install eclipse", as already mentioned in the fedora link above. Maybe you have to enable the dnf module for CentOS.

Answer (score 0):

CentOS 6 includes Eclipse 3.6.1 (Helios) so it's not possible to install Eclipse 3.7 (Indigo) through Yum.

You can either install it manually like Raedwald explained OR you could use Fedora 16 which ships Indigo.

Since RHEL/CentOS is very conservative regarding software versions, I wouldn't expect Indigo to be supported any time soon.

Answer (score 0):

Like the others have answered, you need to install it manually if your yum doesn't have it.

This is the guide I used to do this: http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/linux-install-eclipse-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/

I used it with Fedora 17 which supports Eclipse 4.2 (juno) instead of 3.7 (indigo).

To run them side-by-side you can first install the yum version, then rename `/bin/eclipse` and `/usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop` to something you want like `eclipse-yum` then update `eclipse-yum.desktop` to reference `eclipse-yum`

Finally, install it as the guide explains.